# Was bedeutet „Fleisch“ in „Fleischwurst“?

Tags: etymology

Es gibt viele verschiedene Wursttypen, z.B. Rohwurst, Kochwurst und Fleischwurst. Alle Würste beinhalten Fleisch, aber nicht alle sind Fleischwürste. Was bedeutet „Fleisch“ in „Fleischwurst“? Warum heißen sie so?

Comment: "Fleischwurst" hat einen Fleischanteil von 58% im Namen. :-) (In der realen Wurst dürfte der Fleischanteil sehr gering sein.)

Comment: Es gibt aber auch Tofuwürste für Vegetarier, und Marzipanwürste, die kein Fleisch enthalten. Außerdem gibt es Käsekrainer, die Käse enthalten, und Tee- und Bierwurst, und bei Sat.1 die Wurstwurst. Ach ne - das war der Filmfilm. Insbesonder kenne ich (Lyoner) Schinkenfleischwurst (im Ring) und als Pseudo-Wellness-Lightprodukt die Geflügel- oder Putenfleischwurst. Mit Senf nicht schlecht, und mit Zwiebeln in der Pfanne + Curry u. Reis auch heiß verzehrbar.

Comment: @user: Ich wurde sagen, dass Tofuwürste und Pseudo-Wellness-Light-ohne-Fleisch-Würste nicht Würste sind.

Comment: Eine Pseudo-Wellness-Lightwurst ist die Putenfleischwurst, und die ist nicht ohne Fleisch, sondern setzt auf die Erwartung, dass Putenfleisch oft mager ist, und daher die Würste fettarm. Florianbs Antwort jedoch entnehme ich, dass manchmal nur Rind und Schwein als Fleisch im engeren Sinne betrachtet wird. Erinnerte mich an eine Popdiva, die sich als Vegetarierin bezeichnete, und als Lieblingsgerichte Geflügel, Lamm, Wild und Fisch aufzählte, oder so ähnlich.

Answer (score 7):

Mit Bezug auf die ["Leitsätze für Fleisch und Fleischerzeugnisse"](http://www.bmelv.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/Ernaehrung/Lebensmittelbuch/LeitsaetzeFleisch.pdf?__blob=publicationFile) vom 04.02.2010 – herausgegeben vom Bundesministerium für Ernährung, Landwirtschaft und Verbraucherschutz (BRD) – bestehen alle "Fleischerzeugnisse" überwiegend aus **"Fleisch"**.

> "Fleisch sind alle Teile von geschlachteten oder erlegten warmblütigen Tieren, die zum Genuß für Menschen bestimmt sind." (LfFuF I.1.)
>   Hierbei ist zu beachten, dass der Leitsatz die Höchstwerte für Fett- und Bindegewebeanteile der Zutaten vorschreibt.

Eine Fleischwurst besteht also überwiegend aus "Fleisch", was somit eine Art Gütesiegel darstellt.

> Fleisch in seiner reinen Form bezieht sich im übrigen auf Rinder- oder Schweinefleisch. Die Verwendung anderer Fleischsorten wird "[…] in der [jeweiligen] Verkehrsbezeichnung angegeben, z. B. Hühnerfleischwurst, Hirschsalami". (LfFuF I.2.11 Absatz 2)

Die Leitsätze geben des Weiteren Regeln für die besondere Bezeichnung nach Region und/oder Herstellungsform (Gourmet-Wurst etc.) vor.

Answer (score 2):

Ich vermute, der Begriff *Fleischwurst* soll die Wurstart **von Hartwürsten (auch [Rohwürste](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rohwurst) genannt) abgrenzen**, die klarerweise auch aus Fleisch bestehen, aber länger haltbar sind als die nur kurz haltbare Fleischwurst.

Die Fleischwurst heißt übrigens auch [Lyoner](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyoner) und ist eine Brühwurst (Herstellungdurch Brühen, Braten, Backen) ohne Einlage.

Comment: Na, dann ist meine Vermutung, dass der Name daher rührt, dass jedes Kind einen Namen braucht und man eben die Wurstsorten unterscheiden möchte, vermutlich gar nicht so weit hergeholt. Daher +1. Der Grimm hat übrigens nur *fleischwurst, f. mit gehacktem fleisch gefüllt.*

Comment: Bei uns zuhause (und ich glaube auch in Österreich) nennen wir sie auch "Schinkenwurst"; oder ist das was anderes? Ist mir eigentlich Wurst. ;)

Comment: @splattne: Klares +1 für den Kommentar. Im Zweifel zeige ich an der Wursttheke einfach auf die Wurst, die ich will. Das führt absurderweise dazu, dass ich lauter Sorten kaufe, deren Namen mir nicht bekannt sind, und nächstes mal muss ich dann nachfragen, wie die eigentlich genannt wird ;)

Comment: Wikipedia behauptet beim Fleischkäse (Leberkäse), dass das ein Schweizer Begriff wäre: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leberk%C3%A4se

Comment: @splattne: Es scheint sich um Extrawurst zu handeln, was nicht dasselbe wie Schinkenwurst ist.

Comment: Ja @thei, Fleischwurst ist bei in Österreich Extrawurst und **nicht** Schinkenwurst @splattne.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann es dir leider nicht mit einer Quelle belegen, allerdings vermute ich, dass die Fleischwurst so heißt, da sie mit Hackfleisch oder Pökelfleisch erzeugt wird, das nun entweder reines Rindsfleisch oder mit Schweinefleisch gemischt ist. Es ist also in der Zubereitung eine starke Unschärfe, daher wohl der sehr allgemeine Name.

Außerdem habe ich bei der Recherche erfahren, dass in Deutschland die Fleischwurst nicht nur eine Wurstsorte sondern auch eine Wurstkategorie ist. Lyoner kann (zB in der Schweiz) die Fleischwurst sein, aber auch nur eine davon (zB im Saarland). Bierwurst und Gelbwurst sind allerdings Fleischwurstarten, siehe hierzu die [Diskussion über den Wikipedia Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_Diskussion%3aEssen_und_Trinken/Archiv/2008-2#Fleischwurst).
In Österreich hingegen ist die [Extrawurst](http://www.traditionelle-lebensmittel.at/article/articleview/87138/1/26099) eine eigene Wurstsorte, die es in zwei Arten gibt (fein & grob/ordinär).
Auch herausgefunden habe ich, dass die Wurst auf jeden Fall schon lang bekannt ist, weswegen der Ursprung des Namens wohl im Dunkeln liegt.