# Was bedeutet "Zieher" im Wort "Schraubenzieher"?

Tags: etymology

Angeregt durch die Frage [Was bedeutet „Fleisch“ in „Fleischwurst“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/693/was-bedeutet-fleisch-in-fleischwurst) kann ich mir die Frage

`Was bedeutet "Zieher" im Wort "Schraubenzieher"?`

nicht verkneifen.

`Schraubenzieher` ist eine früher übliche Bezeichnung für ein Werkzeug, welches heute korrekt als `Schraubendreher` bezeichnet wird, was auch die Funktion wesentlich klarer beschreibt.

Comment: Heißt es nicht: "man zieht die Schraube fest (an)"? Ich hab "Schraubendreher" jedenfalls noch nie gehört, komisches Wort. ^^

Comment: Die korrekte Bezeichnung müsste dann wohl eigentlich `Schraubeneinausdreher` sein.

Comment: Werkzeugkataloge verwenden es. Schau mal in den Baumarkt.

Comment: @ladybug: Ja, heißt es, siehe mein Zitat des Grimms :)

Comment: Wenn alles so exakt wäre, müsste ein Schraubenschlüssel ja eigentlich... ähm... was machen? ;)

Comment: @bernd_k: Ich würde "Schraubendreher" nicht als _korrekter_ bezeichnen. Was sollen all die Zitronenfalter und Buchmacher dazu sagen?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt Zumindest hatten sich mir nicht gleich die Nackenhaare gesträubt, als ich es das erste Mal gehört hatte.

Comment: Schraubenzieher ist noch immer weit verbreitet; die Behauptung, der Ausdruck sein inkorrekt, müsste erst untermauert werden.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eintrag im Grimm:

> schraubenzieher, m. *werkzeug zum anziehen oder lockern der schrauben* **Jacobsson** 4, 43a: er zog schlösser und einen schraubenzieher aus der tasche. **Freytag** *handschrift 3, 174*; lasz mir den schraubenzieher nicht so ausglitschen .. mach die schrauben eine nach der andern halb los und dann erst ganz. **Keller** 6, 261.

Man *zieht* also Schrauben *an*.

Comment: Ich glaube wenige haben das so empfunden, daher auch der geringe Widerstand gegen die neue Bezeichnung.

Comment: Geringer Widerstand? Alle, die ich kenne, sagen Schraubenzieher :) Außerdem kann man Schrauben auch fest- oder nachziehen. Die Herkunft ist daher in meinen Augen auch heute noch nachvollziehbar.

Comment: +1 für die Ethymologie. In Österreich ist "Schraubenzieher" vollkommen übliche Sprache. Der Dreher hingegen ist nur an Technischen (Hoch)Schulen/Fachhochschulen gebräuchlich. Meist auch nur um Schüler und Studenten mit "Das heißt dreher, du ziehst ja deine Schraube nicht" zu ärgern ;)

Comment: Der Schraubendreher ist ja schon der Mensch der an der Drehbank sitzt und den Schrauben das Gewinde dreht. ;)

Comment: @Samuel Herzog: Kiek an. Hier im hohen Norden ist auch eigentlich nur Schraubenzieher gebräuchlich, außer von ein paar ganz Schlauen. In erster Näherung geht der Gebrauch also vom nördlichen bis zum südlichen Ende des deutschen Sprachraums, interpoliert müsste es dazwischen genauso sein ;)

Comment: @swegi: Danke für den ersten Lacher des Tages. Dabei könnte das sogar ein Grund sein, warum Schraubendreher statt Schraubenzieher falsch wäre ;)

Comment: "Schraubenlockerer" wäre auch mal was. Oder als Hauptdarsteller in einem Kinofilm: "Der Schraubenlockeror" :=)

Comment: @swegi: Ich dachte erst, das meinst du eher scherzhaft. Ist es aber gar nicht. Aus dem Grimm: "schraubendreher, m. der durch drehen schrauben formt oder handhabt, auch name eines werkzeugs, womit schrauben umgedreht werden. "

Comment: @OregonGhost: Das war von mir tatsächlich scherzhaft gemeint, aber scheinbar liege ich ja dann gar nicht so falsch.

Comment: @OregonGhost : Werkzeug zum **Umdrehen** von Schrauben? Jetzt wird's ja ganz abenteuerlich...

Answer (score 6):

Schlitzschrauben, für die dieses Werkzeug ja hergestellt wird, sind eine neuere Erfindung als Schrauben generell. In alten Zeiten war der Schraubenantrieb zunächst ein Vierkant und dann ein Sechskant. Solche Schrauben wurden (und werden) mit einem "Schraubenschlüssel" (muss zur Schraube passen wie ein Schlüssel zum Schloss) "angezogen". Ziehen also deshalb, weil der Schraubenschlüssel einen Hebel darstellt. Das hat sich dann auf den Schraubendreher als *Schraubenzieher* übertragen. Korrekt, und soweit ich weiß eine Fachbezeichnung, ist "Schraubendreher".

Comment: +1 Für eine sinnvolle Erklärung.

Comment: Das Wort *Schlüssel* ist schwierig, weil mechanische Schlösser relativ spät erst Verbreitung gefunden haben dürften, doch die Wurzel wird meist als "peg, crook, hook" gedeutet, bezieht sich also generell auf eine Art von mechanischem Zeug. Ein *Schlosser* stellt schließlich nicht nur Schlüssel her. Dabei zeigt die ungewissheit der Rekonstruktion \*(s)kleHw- Problemchen im Vokalismus, was schon auf äußerst frühe Lehnbeziehungen und Verwechslungspotential hinweisen könnte, sodass auch nicht auszu-schließen ist, ob \*(s)kel- wie in *Schlitz* hier her gehöre wie auch \*'kel- "to incline"

Answer (score 5):

Schraubenzieher wird (zumindest in Österreich) erst seit wenigen Jahren vom Schraubendreher bedrängt (als Bezeichnung in Fachliteratur, Baumärkten etc. durchaus gängig). Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch (auch in der Belletristik) hat der Schraubendreher, obwohl stimmiger, sich noch längst nicht durchgesetzt und das wird wohl noch länger (Jahrzehnte?) so bleiben.

Comment: Schraubendreher ist Bürokratendeutsch.

Answer (score 1):

Naja, man kann den Schraubendreher verwenden, um Schrauben aus dem Holz zu drehen bzw. ziehen. (Obwohl hierbei eigentlich keine Zugbewegung stattfindet). Daher wahrscheinlich Schraubenzieher.

Comment: Es gibt auch viele Arten Schraubendreher als Werkzeug zu missbrauchen. Z.B. als Hebel oder als Spatel. Meistens nehmen sie dabei Schaden indem sie verbiegen oder etwas ausbricht.